# drupal ctools - how to show view in modal

Tags: drupal, modal-dialog, drupal-views, drupal-ctools

I'm wondering how to show a view into a modal? 
Could someone give me an example? Further more I like to call the view out of an action.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Drupal 5 is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this? http://www.angrydonuts.com/ctools-presentation-slides-and-example-code

This is implemented using hook_menu, which offers a means to call the modal (see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/5)

In terms of using an action, I would have thought you could have applied the same code inside your action code (see http://drupal.org/node/142154 "Implementation of a Drupal Action"), but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that, but have you clue how to "click" a menu item within the action. The action should release the modal..